# Do I need to set a foreign key for table row increments on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forum

That title is way wrong, I couldn't think of a better sentence.

I'm creating a PHP/MySQL bases forum where I want to display how many topics are in a particular forum. So far so good, my question is: how do I make the row for topic count increment each time I add a new topic under a forum and decrement when I delete a topic.

I could make this happen in the script but maybe there's a better way to do this from the database?

Thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: Use triggers. Of even better select the count on the fly or in a view

Comment: Sounds like you just want something like `SELECT f.name, COUNT(t.id) topicCount FROM forum f LEFT JOIN topic t ON t.forumId = f.id GROUP BY f.name`

Comment: Yeah exactly! Thanks @phil :) Thanks a million. Thanks for your input juergen-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily include counts of one-to-many relationships in a single query using a `COUNT` aggregation and `GROUP BY`. For example

```
SELECT f.id, f.name, COUNT(t.id) as topicCount
FROM forum f
LEFT JOIN topic t
    ON f.id = topic.forumId
GROUP BY f.id, f.name
```